# Enumerate level 2 reference format

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

In the following example, when I refer the `enumerate` level 2, it comes out 2a instead of 2 (a). How can I change that?

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item Iadfagas
 \item adf 
\begin{enumerate}
 \item \label{item:a} af a
 \item \label{item:aa} asd
 \item \label{item:b} asfa
 \item \label{item:c} af a
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\ref{item:a} follows from Proposition
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

With `enumitem` package, you can use:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{ref=\theenumi(\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{ref=\theenumii\roman*}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{ref=\theenumi(\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{ref=\theenumii\roman*}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item Iadfagas
 \item adf
\begin{enumerate}
 \item \label{item:a} af a
 \item \label{item:aa} asd
 \item \label{item:b} asfa
 \item \label{item:c} af a
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\ref{item:a} follows from Proposition
\end{document}
```

[image]

As pointed out by Gonzalo, you may wish to modify the `\ref` for third level also by adding

```
\setlist[enumerate,3]{ref=\theenumii\roman*}
```

to get rid of the extra parenthesis in referring to an item in that level.

Answer (score 5):

Without any packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theenumii{(\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{(\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi\theenumii}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item Iadfagas
 \item adf 
\begin{enumerate}
 \item \label{item:a} af a
 \item \label{item:aa} asd
 \item \label{item:b} asfa
 \item \label{item:c} af a
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\ref{item:a} follows from Proposition
\end{document}
```

[image]