# change the format of \ref (enumerate package)

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

I am writing a list of questions using `enumerate package`.

Something like this :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{itm:1} This is the question 1
\item \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item \label{itm:2a} This is the question 2.(a)
\item This is the question 2.(b)
\item \begin{enumerate}[-i)]
\item \label{itm:2ci}This is the question 2.(c)-i)
\item This is the question 2.(c)-ii)
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\ref{itm:1},\ref{itm:2a} and \ref{itm:2ci} 

\end{document}
```

`\ref{itm:1},\ref{itm:2a} and \ref{itm:2ci}` gives respectively 1, 2a and 2(c)i

how can I change the format of \ref to get

1. , 2.(a) and 2.(c)-i)

if possible show how can I apply the solution locally and globally for all enumerate of the document.

Comment: related/duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163069/enumerate-level-2-reference-format

Comment: @touhami - While the two postings are obviously related to each other, by the fact that they're about the formatting of labels of and cross-references to enumerated items, the issues raised by this posting are sufficiently distinct so that it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how your objective may be accomplished with the tools of the `enumerate` package (though David Carlisle probably could!), but I know how to accomplish it with the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/) package.

One of the many nice features of the `enumitem` package is that labels of enumerated items and the format of cross-references to these items can be set in a very straightforward way. For first-level items, only the `ref` part needs to be modified (by affixing a "`.`" to `\theenumi`); the second- and third-level items both the `label` and the `ref` parts are modified.

(The code below uses the `hyperref` package to make obvious what the cross-references look like.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} %% just for this example
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[ref=\theenumi.]
\item This is question 1 \label{itm:1} 
\item \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),
                        ref=\theenumi(\theenumii)]
      \item This is question 2.(a) \label{itm:2a} 
      \item This is question 2.(b)
      \item \begin{enumerate}[label=-\roman*),
                              ref=\theenumii-\theenumiii)]
            \item This is question 2.(c)-i) \label{itm:2ci}
            \item This is question 2.(c)-ii)
            \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Questions \ref{itm:1}, \ref{itm:2a}, and \ref{itm:2ci} \dots

\end{document}
```

---

Your formatting goals, for both the labels and the cross-references, could also be achieved without the aid of any package, by using the following low-level LaTeX instructions instead. Note, though, that these instructions apply to *all* subsequent enumerated environments.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{(\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand\theenumii{(\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand\labelenumiii{-\roman{enumiii})}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{-\roman{enumiii})}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi\theenumii}
\makeatother
```

---

If you have several enumerated lists of this type, it is handy to create a dedicated enumerate-like environment that sets up all the formatting instructions, using the `\newlist` and `\setlist` instructions of the `enumitem` package. For instance, you might set up the following code (no new screenshot, as the output is the same as in the preceding example):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{enumitem}    
\newlist{qenum}{enumerate}{3}  % create a new enumerate-like environment
\setlist[qenum,1]{label=\arabic*.,
                  ref=\arabic*.}
\setlist[qenum,2]{label=(\alph*),
                  ref=\theqenumi(\alph*)}
\setlist[qenum,3]{label=-\roman*),
                  ref=\theqenumii-\roman*)}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} %% just for this example

\begin{document}

\begin{qenum}
\item This is question 1 \label{itm:1} 
\item \begin{qenum}
      \item This is question 2.(a) \label{itm:2a} 
      \item This is question 2.(b)
      \item \begin{qenum}
            \item This is question 2.(c)-i) \label{itm:2ci}
            \item This is question 2.(c)-ii)
            \end{qenum}
      \end{qenum}
\end{qenum}

Questions \ref{itm:1}, \ref{itm:2a}, and \ref{itm:2ci} \dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I will wait a little bit for Carlisle  before accepting this answer. I have an additional question concerning `enumitem` package : how can I redefine the default format of `label` and `ref` ?

Comment: @AymaneFihadi - When working with `enumitem`, there are basically few defaults: The package makes it very straightforward to change just about anything, but the downside (if it's even a downside) is that there are very few "default" values: *You* can (and must) specify the settings for `\label` and `\ref`. Does this answer your follow-up query?

Comment: Just for clarification, do you mean I have to specify the values of ref and label in every list of question in the same document ?

Comment: @AymaneFihadi - Thanks for the clarification. I'll post an addendum that shows how to set up a custom enumeration environment.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for all your help.