# Referencing a list item no bracket appearing?

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

I am referencing an item in a list using the style `[i]`, and package `enumerate`.

My text goes something like this :

```
\begin{enumerate}[(i)] 
\item\label{item 1}

\end{enumerate}
blah blah \ref{item 1}.
```

But the output is "blah blah i" instead of with the brackets "blah blah (i)". Whats going on here?

Comment: `enumitem` package may be better.

Comment: By the way please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: Yes, switching to enumitem package fixes it immediately (read the documentation for how to use it. You may want `shortlabels` package option) Also similar question [cross referencing - change the format of \ref (enumerate package) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255849/change-the-format-of-ref-enumerate-package) also suggest that package

Comment: @DanielAdams There most likely is a way (worst case, copy paste the source code of the other package into your TeX file), but I'm not interested in figuring out how at the moment...